# GIT Make local branch pull from remote1/master and push to remote2/legacy

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have seen that you can add a remote and state that it's pushurl is another remote.

For example, if I set my origin as

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:newrepo/newrepo.git
```

I can add a new remote and set its `pushurl` to my origin:

```
git remote add oldremote git@github.com:oldrepo/oldrepo.git
git remote set-url --push oldremote git@github.com:newrepo/newrepo.git
```

So if I create a branch `branch1` from `oldremote/branch1`

```
git fetch oldremote branch1
git checkout -b branch1 oldremote/branch1
```

It will pull from `oldremote/branch1` and push to `origin/branch1`

This works as expected. Doing `git pull` pulls from `oldremote` (and says we're up to date) and pushes to `origin`. Nice and easy.

Now I'm trying to create a branch that doesn't have the same name as its  remote branch. Secifically, I want to track `oldremote/master` as local branch `legacy`, and have this local branch to push to `origin/legacy`.

```
git fetch oldremote master
git checkout -b legacy oldremote/master
```

Now, this has two side effects.

First, doing `git push` doesn't push to `origin/legacy`. I have to do `git push origin legacy`.

Second, doing `git pull` doesn't just fetch and merge from `oldremote/master`. It fetches every branch from `oldremote`.

**TL/DR**

Is there a way to pull from a branch in one remote and push to another branch in another remote when branch names are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config branch.legacy.remote oldremote
git config branch.legacy.pushremote origin
git config branch.legacy.merge refs/heads/master
```

`git config --local -e` should look like:

```
[remote "oldremote"]
    url = git@github.com:oldrepo/oldrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/oldremote/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:newrepo/newrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = oldremote
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "legacy"]
    remote = oldremote
    pushremote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Note that the value of `push.default` should be unset or `simple`. As the manual says, `simple` has become the default in Git 2.0. If its value is not `simple` or unset, `git push` may fail.

Comment: I had no idea about the `pushremote` setting. I'll give it a shot

Comment: It works! The only annoyance is that doing git pull when stepping on the legacy branch, it fetches every branch and every tag of the oldremote repo. But I guess I can live with that.